# Reading Attribute Accessors Sent Through Via Form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and using a simple mailer function to pass a few attribute accessors through to a email template I have.

My model looks like this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :replace_1, :model_id

end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
def model_replace
  @model= Model.find(params[:model][:model_id])

  UserMailer.replacement_model(@model).deliver
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to({ :action => "model_replace"}, :notice => 'Model has been replaced.') }
  end
end
```

My Form looks like this:

```
 # Form stuff bound to Model

<div class="radio"><%= f.check_box :replace_1 %></div>
<%= f.hidden_field(:model_id, :value =>model.id)
```

My mailer works fine and passes the model to the following simple .erb file:

```
<p>Hello, the value of replace_1 is <%=@model.replace_1 %></p>
```

I know the model is being passed through as I am able to access "@model.User.user_id" for example, successfully.

Also in the rails terminal I can see the data being submitted - "model" => { "replace_1" => "1" }

Could some one help me, I'm returning a blank value for the replace_1 in my erb file.

thanks.

Comment: what does your controller look like

Comment: Updated Question with controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the parameter into my controller via:

```
def model_replace
@model= Model.find(params[:model][:model_id])

@model.replace_1 = params[:model][:replace_1]

UserMailer.replacement_model(@model).deliver
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to({ :action => "model_replace"}, :notice => 'Model has been replaced.') }
 end
end
```

I then simply accessed it in my .erb file via:

@model.replace_1

Seems a bit dirty, but it's working.  Hope it helps anyone stuck with this newbie issue, and I'm open to any improved methods at performing this functionality.

Thanks!